# Can I paste blocks of contents in MIT App Inventor?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am using app inventor for a school project, and I need to use a block of contents and paste it every time a function is called.

My idea is to do it like if it were a fragment in Android Studio, but it seems impossible...

Any ideas?
[image: This is what I want to copy to the other screens (VerticalArrangment)]

This is what I want to copy to the other screens (VerticalArrangment)

Answer (score 1):

Fragments are not available in MIT App Inventor.

**Use different screens wisely!** Before starting to create another screen, first you should think about is it really necessary? See also [Building apps with many screens](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/manyscreens.html) and [SteveJG's post about advantages/disadvantages](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/ka-LS7wmWxs/wRbs70x2BgAJ).

What about using only one screen together with your layout... For example add 2 buttons "Previous" and "Next" together with some logic to display some other content using the same components...

---

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

Comment: Thanks for the help! But what I really need is a way to create new blocks of contents by code, as that's what I need for my app. Is there any way to do something dimilar to that?

Comment: you can't create components during runtime of your app. What you can do is to prepare some components and hide them and as soon as you need them, then set them to visible = true...

Comment: Okey, but what I want to do is to create a new component with different information on it (which is given by the user) every time a button is clicked. Is that posible?

Comment: no, as already said, you can't create components during runtime. Use your existing components to display the new data